# Why does my Android camera app have no preview in the multitasking viewer?

Tags: android, camera, multitasking

I have put together small camera app in Android. My problem is that I dont get a preview image in the multitasking viewer (the view you get when you hit the multitaskbutton in pure android)

In my case, my app just shows a black preview. Why is that the case? And, how can I make my app show the frozen image of the camera preview? Do I have to save that somehow?

Thanks, any advice is really appreciated!

Comment: What are you using for your preview surface? `TextureView` or `SurfaceView`?

Comment: I am using surfaceview

Comment: I suspect that if you use `TextureView`, at least on API Level 14+, it will work. I seem to recall that my CWAC-Camera library samples show a preview image in the recent-tasks list, and they use `TextureView` where possible.